# arrangement of data in known formatted file

Tags: c++

I have a question about arrangement of data in known formatted file. it kind of complex so I hope I get it right. this is the question:

I have measurements on several families, their data changes every day.
my goal is to write into files all the measurements (in c++), but as organized and clear as it gets.

this is the format i need:

```
several files- file name: family_name
```

every file contains:

```
family member 1:
                 day1   ,   day2   ,   day3   ...
weight:
height: 
blood pressure:
etc...


family member 2:
                 day1   ,   day2   ,   day3   ...
weight:
height: 
blood pressure:
etc...


family member 3:
                 day1   ,   day2   ,   day3   ...
weight:
height: 
blood pressure:
etc...
```

is there some kind of well known c++ library which I can easily (on run time):

```
1. make the table (number of rows and columns)
2. give title for every column and every row
3. insert data to specific cell 
4. save it as arranged file
```

thanks.

Comment: One solution could be using CSV format. It could be opened with spreadsheet software.

Comment: It looks, that you need database. Try this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to re-implement a COBOL like record oriented file access, I think you are best off reading the whole file into an internal data representation, inserting or updating the data in question and then re-writing the whole file.

I see two basic options for that.

1. Use a serialization library in order to produce output not formatted as simple text but e.g. as Json or XML. Perhaps boost can help.

   **Advantage:** Accessibility with all kinds of tools which work on open standard formats (spreadsheets, databases, editors). Easy generation of various output formats like plain Ascii, HTML, PDF etc.

   **Disadvantage:** Direct human readability is limited (but still possible if the serialization is to a text format like one of the above).
2. Roll your own serialization. Not too difficult for simple data. Create an output and an input routine for each "record" and its "sub records" using the standard `iostream` facilities or, probably easier, `printf`/`scanf`.

   **Advantage:** Perfect human readability, complete format control.

   **Disadvantage:** No accessibility with tools like spreadsheets and databases (probably the biggest long-term disadvantage which will come back and bite you). Perhaps more work to begin with. Each output format needs a complete re-write of the serialization functionality.